# Preferences page not opening to same page? - Jailbroken iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, settings, preferences, jailbreak

I am trying to create a jailbreak tweak that implements a settings bundle(via PreferenceLoader). The problem is that when you exit the settings app by clicking the home button, then reopen the settings app, it opens to the main (base) settings page. Testing other tweaks that I have installed, when you reopen the settings app, it opens to the app page that it was closed on. How can I do this with my tweak?

Thanks!

EDIT:
My whole settings page is a custom PSViewController with my custom code, I am not just loading preferences from a .plist.

EDIT:
Is this problem occurring because no object is holding a strong reference to my custom controller or what?

Comment: Do you have any **code** executing in your settings bundle, or is it just a standard plist file?

Comment: I have a custom view controller that handles everything and nothing is being loaded from a .plist. I can post the code if you want but there's a lot of it.